# How to extract AIC from polr summary output in R

Tags: r, regression, extract, ordinal, mass-package

I'd like to quickly compare AICs that are provided as output when running `summary()` on individual `polr()` models created using the `MASS` package in R. I have no problem compiling this info, but what I can't figure out is *where* exactly the AIC info is being stored in the `polr` model objects themselves.

I've tried using `str()` and `attributes()` on my model objects, and I've even tried using `getAnywhere("polr")` to look at the source code itself. Nothing is standing out to me.

**Anyone know how to extract AIC output from `summary(polr_mod)`?**

Example for reference:

```
library(MASS)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = factor(rep(0:2,each=3),ordered = T), v2 = rep(1:3,each=3))
mod_polr <- polr(v1 ~ v2, data = dat, Hess = T, method = "logistic" )
summary(mod_polr)

Call:
polr(formula = v1 ~ v2, data = dat, Hess = T, method = "logistic")

Coefficients:
     v2 
46.7233 

Intercepts:
      0|1       1|2 
 73.62014 117.05781 

Residual Deviance: 1.560782e-08 
AIC: 6.00
```

^ See, at the bottom of the output is `AIC: 6.00`. Where is this stored in the object? I'd like to call/extract it.

Comment: You can extract it with `stats::AIC(mod_polr)`.

Comment: Thanks, @danh! That works. Though, I'd love to see an explanation for why that works as a formal answer.

Comment: You could take a look at the guts of `AIC()` here: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/AIC.R

Answer (score 3):

`AIC` is a generic function with no method for objects of class `"polr"` but with a default method.
The default method's code can be seen by running

```
getAnywhere("AIC.default")
```

and what it does is to call `logLik` on its first argument and then to compute the AIC with `k = 2`.
The number of model parameters is given by

```
attr(lls, "df")
```

And the computation is

```
lls <- logLik(mod_polr)
-2*as.numeric(lls) + k*attr(lls, "df")
```

In its turn, `logLik` is also generic but with a method for objects of class `"polr"`.
The code returned by

```
getAnywhere("logLik.polr")
```

is very simple, a one-liner. Note that the `df` in its code was `edf` in the object `"polr"`. Indented it's the following.

```
logLik.polr <- function(object, ...) {
  structure(
    -0.5 * object$deviance, 
    df = object$edf, 
    nobs = object[["nobs"]], 
    class = "logLik"
  )
}
```

The explanation for the `deviance`, `edf` and `nobs` are found in `help("polr)`, section Value.

> deviance
> the residual deviance.

> edf
> the (effective) number of degrees of freedom used by the model

And like that section says, `nobs` is used for `stepAIC` (but not for `logLik.polr`).

So this can all be pieced together in one function.
Write a `AIC` method for objects of class `"polr"` simplifying the code above.

```
AIC.polr <- function(x, k = 2){
  dev <- x$deviance
  nparams <- x$edf
  dev + k*nparams
}

AIC(mod_polr)
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score -1):

I know that tihs is an old question ut I just want to share in case others have the same question and want another option.

Using modelsummary() to create your regression tabel then you also get AIC, BIC and RMSE. If you need example let me know.

Comment: modelsummary() is not a function in any of the packages loaded for this question.

Comment: I didn't wrote that it is, so? This method just worked for me and I wanted to share.

Comment: If you suggest a function that you found useful, it is helpful to also mention which package it came from so that others can benefit. I tried to use your suggestion but cannot because I do not know which package to install/load.

Comment: Sorry for that! the package/library it self is called modelsummary and the function is also called modelsummary(). And example is used here: https://modelsummary.com/articles/modelsummary.html